# How to delete unapproved app from iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, testing, ios8, testflight

I'm using now the new Apple service for testing apps. 
I know that the process to send an app for test is:

- Create an ID
- Create the certificates
- Create an app in iTunesConnect
- Archive, upload and invite internal or external test.

But not all apps that I create in my account (iTunesConnect) go to be public; because a lot of my app finish published in the accounts of my costumers.
In this way in my iTunesConnect I have a lot of: (for example)

- App1 Test
- App2 Test
- App3 test
  ....

I want to delete these, is there a way?

If what I wrote is wrong, so there is another way more intelligent to follow, tell me please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot delete apps from iTunes Connect unless one or more versions of the app have been approved by Apple's review team. According to their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html):

> You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app

Honestly, aside from the annoyance of seeing old unused apps there, there isn't much of a problem with what you're doing. What you could do to reduce the number of "junk" apps in your portal is to re-use app identifiers after the TestFlight testing time of 30 days expires (and, of course, you'll have to clear out those beta testers).

Comment: YEAH!!!... good idea... reuse the same app for test... ouch!!! Why I didn't think before!!! thanks man!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can Not delete it before atleast one of the versions of your app is approved!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, other people can't use your undeleted App names. I had an old one on my account that another Developer wanted to use. I got this letter from Apple:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> **Please include **** in the subject line of any future correspondence on this matter.**
>
> On 3/4/2016, we received a notice from **** (“Complainant”) that
>   Complainant believes your application named "****" infringes
>   Complainant’s intellectual property rights.  In particular,
>   Complainant believes you are infringing its app name, thereby blocking
>   Complainant from using it on the App Store.